# everything-upto-date error on git cmd / github desktop

Tags: git, github, github-desktop

i have 6 commits on my repo and whenever I push I get an error. I think it has to do with it being a unity project but i don't know.

N really sure what else to put here.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

That might be because of the large size of the commits you are pushing:

```
Writing objects: 100%... 2,05GB
```

See "[Working with large files and repositories](https://github.community/t/working-with-large-files-and-repositories/10203)":

> we don’t allow pushes over 2GB. I

You might have to consider [Git LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com/) for such large files.

Comment: can i have a quick rundown how to use it? command line says lfs is not a command and i ran the exe download but i dont see much

Comment: @Futuremappermydud https://git-lfs.github.com/ should give you a quick rundown on how to use it, starting with the installation step (`git lfs install`). But check first it is the issue: do you have large files? Or are you simply pushing too many commits whose combined size it too important?

Comment: sorry for semi late reply i think im pushing alot of files/commits who have a slight large size anyway i could bring all the changes from those commits back and remove them so i can choose what too leave out? like i can remove un needed library files

Comment: @Futuremappermydud Ideally, if you don't have too many commits, you would `git reset` to an old one (https://stackoverflow.com/a/53878312/6309), modify `.gitignore` to ignore the libraries/large files, add, and recreate your commits you were trying to push (this time without large files)

Comment: thats the thing.... i have 6 commits with quite a large sum of stuff done

Comment: @Futuremappermydud Then use https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo which can delete large files from  old commits.